# Firefox addon calling code from another script file

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Following is folder structure and manifest file for test addon;

```
- borderify
  - content
    - calc.js              ; create html UI elements
    - operations.js        ; assign js functions to UI elements
  - popup
    - html popup file with option to call calc.js
    - choose_page.css
    - test.js
  - background.js
  - borderify.js
  - manifest.json
```

Not able to call code of `operations.js`from `calc.js`
Tried include("name of js file") (custom func to inject .js) and import statements, but none worked.
Tried merging calc.js and operation.js but html events don't get trigger.
Rest of calc.js file functions are working properly, only importing operations.js fails.

What is way to include/import code/function from another js file if caller file is in;

1. content folder
2. popup folder
3. root folder

Manifest.json

```
"browser_action"      : {
        "browser_style": true,
        "default_icon": "icons/border-48.png",
        "default_title": "Borderify v1",
        "default_popup": "popup/choose_page.html"
    },
"background"          : {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]  
  },
"content_scripts"     : [{
       "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["borderify.js"],
        "run_at":"document_end"
  },
  ],
"permissions" : ["activeTab", "contextMenus", "menus", "notifications", "tabs", "storage", "<all_urls>"]
}
```